# Angular Input Validator, Promise undefined error

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous, promise

Trying to check if email exists or not by using my API in Angular.

I cannot use HttpClient to check email. Tried many ways and search online but no result.

Validator Codes:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './../services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserFormValidators {
static _userService:UserService;
static _http:HttpClient;

constructor(private userService:UserService, http:HttpClient){
    UserFormValidators._userService=this.userService;
    UserFormValidators._http = http;
}

static emailExists(control:AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> 
{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let emailValue = control.value as string;
        let result:boolean=false;
        setTimeout(()=>{ 

            this._http.get("https://localhost:44366/api/users/checkemail?email="+emailValue)
            .pipe(
                map(res=>{ result = res as boolean; })
            );

            if(result){
            resolve({ emailExists:true });
            }else{
                resolve(null);
            }
        },2000);
      
    });
 }
 }
```

[image]

It is always showing me this error.

Any help?

Comment: You don't need to add private before http:HttpClient in `constructor(private userService:UserService, http:HttpClient)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use FormGroup, FormBuilder, and RxJS :

```js
form: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private userService: UserService,
  private http: HttpClient,
  fb: FormBuilder
) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

emailExists(): void {
  // You can display a loader here like : this.loader = true;
  const params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.set('email', this.form.get('email').value;

  this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:44366/api/users/checkemail", params)
  .pipe(
    map(res => !!res ? { emailExists: true } : null)
  ).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // You can hide a loader here like : this.loader = false;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<button (click)="emailExists()">Check email</button>
```

I did it quickly and have not tested it.